# Basic mean calculation

Tags: r, mean

V1  is the frequency of V2 
Is there a easy way to calulate the V2 mean? Or do i have to transform my table?

my data is structured like this:

```
V1   V2
2   18042
12  18043
4   18044
13  18045
11  18046
1   18047
6   18048
1   18049
3   18050
14  18051
1   18052
....
```

Comment: Could you please show what has already failed? `mean(df$V2)`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are your thoughts about how to approach this problem.

Comment: Use `weighted.mean` with V1 as the weights (w argument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sum` like

```
sum(x$V1*x$V2) / sum(x$V1)
```